# How exactly to read CosmosDB Metrics charts

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to get my mind around metrics charts in azure portal for CosmosDB and i find it a bit confusing.

For example, i get charts like this:

[image: cosmosdb metrics]

[image]

What confuses me in particular is how to read combination of charts 1 and 3?
chart 1 shows a spike of roughly 100RU. That would mean, if there would be 4 times more, it would start with requests throttling.

On the other hand, chart 3 suggests that there is still alot of capacity left untill provisioned 400RU limit is met.

So, what should be concluded here about when will the first throttled request occur? in 3x more as with spike or in ~100x more as suggested by chart 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph 3 shows the average, which is pretty flat. Graph 1 shows actual RU/s consumed. It looks as though you had a temporary spike in RU consumption - perhaps even one query. Throttling is performed on a per second basis. To answer your question, if you had 3x more consumption in a single second, you'd be throttled.